# How to display the ImageView at a desired position in a custom listview in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-custom-view, listviewitem

Recently I made a app that will display a list of data in a custom listview.
This custom listview will display a list of texts and a image views, and I've implemented a simple logic that will display a icon "new info" if date string  matches with the  date string from the json, and if the position of the list item is in 0.(The first position).When the date string matches and the position is in the 0'th place, the "new icon "  gets set, and I want it to be set only in the first position, however, the "new icon " gets set in a random positon such as 9th or 18th position. Is the logic I implemented  wrong? However the logic for this is simple, I started to loose track of what's going on since, more "new icon " starts to show up when I scroll down the list view. For testing purposes I've set the Toast to see the items position, but I see that even though the position and the date doesn't match in the if statement, the icon still shows.
I've set the sample code below.

```
    //Compares the ArrayList<String> with the String and checks if position is in the first place

    if (lastdays.get(position).trim().toString().equals("2015/05/14")&&(position==0)) {

                    logicflag = true;
            //displays a "new icon" if the condition is true

                    holder.left.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blinker);
                    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) holder.left
                            .getBackground();

                    // Start the animation (looped playback by default).
                    frameAnimation.start();

                }else {
//if false, displays nothing
                    holder.left.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                }
    //will display a "2nd and a 3rd new icon" to the 2nd & 3nd position if the logicflag = true
                if((position==1||position==2)&&logicflag){

                    holder.left.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_icon);

                }else{
                    // holder.left.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                }

//always keeps the last position with nothing
                if(position==getCount()-1){
                     holder.left.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                }

            }
```

Afterall, all I want to do is to display the image "new icon" in the 0'th position and if the string matches.

PS: I've set the dummy date string to test it but failed.

Comment: Your `lastdays.get(position).trim().toString().equals("2015/05/14")` not satisfy. You should use valid `SimpleDateFormat` and then compare that value with your date.

Comment: Actually, to show a sample I wrote "2015/05/14" but actually I'm comparing the string that I converted from a Japanese Time like, Time `time = new Time("Asia/Tokyo");
    time.setToNow();
       String today = time.year + "年" + (time.month+1) + "月" + time.monthDay + "日";`  .Therefore, I'm actually comparing string "2015年05月14日"